hp laser printer 109-m112 stop automatic printer adding
How to I stop Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS from automatically adding printers?I have an HP Laser 109-m112

If you're using Ubuntu 22.04.2 as you state, I suggest you apply all security upgrades asap as you're months behind currently (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 22.04.3, but installed systems upgraded before that date, and upgraded systems won't report themselves as 22.04.3 anymore either!)
